# Javascript: understanding map and reduce applied to a tip calculator

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary, reduce

I created a tip calculator using if-else statements as below:

```
var billRestaurant1 = 124;
var billRestaurant2 = 48;
var billRestaurant3 = 268;


function myTip (bill) {
    if (bill < 50) {
        var tip = bill * 20 / 100;
        return tip;
    } else if (bill > 49 && bill < 200) {
        var tip = bill * 15 / 100;
        return tip;
    } else {
        var tip = bill * 10 / 100;
        return tip;
    }
}

var tipRestaurant1 = myTip(billRestaurant1);
var tipRestaurant2 = myTip(billRestaurant2);
var tipRestaurant3 = myTip(billRestaurant3);

// console.log(tipRestaurant1, tipRestaurant2, tipRestaurant3)
var sumOfTips = [tipRestaurant1, tipRestaurant2, tipRestaurant3]
console.log(sumOfTips);

var sumOfBillsAndTips = [(billRestaurant1 + tipRestaurant1),(billRestaurant2 + tipRestaurant2),(billRestaurant3 + tipRestaurant3)];
console.log(sumOfBillsAndTips);
```

The calculator returns two arrays: one with the sum of tips and one with the total amount spent (bill + tip).

A friend of mine suggested me, to learn functional programming, to work with map and reduce to create the same application.

At the moment the code below returns an array of 3 NaN: could you please help me completing it and understanding it?
Thank you so much.

```
const data = [
  {"bill":120, "user_entered_tip": 10},
  {"bill":70, "user_entered_tip": 15},
  {"bill":25, "user_entered_tip": 20}
];

const get_sum = function(data){
    return data.reduce(function(prev, curr){
        return prev + curr
    },0);
};

const get_bill = function(bill, key){

    return bill.map(function(currentValue){
        return currentValue + (currentValue * (currentValue[key] / 100));
  });
};


console.dir(get_bill(data, "user_entered_tip"))
```

Comment: In your map function you forgot the "bill" key:
return currentValue.bill + (currentValue.bill * (currentValue[key] / 100));

Comment: And same for your `reduce`, you forgot the "bill" key. You need to do something like `prev + curr.bill` (or `prev + curr.bill + curr.user_entered_tip` if that's what you're going for).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved thanks to the comments of m.void and SamVK:

```
const data = [
    {"bill":120, "user_entered_tip": 10},
  {"bill":70, "user_entered_tip": 15},
  {"bill":25, "user_entered_tip": 20}
];

const get_sum = function(bill, key){
    return bill.map(function(currentValue){
        return (currentValue.bill * (currentValue[key] / 100));
  });
};

const get_bill = function(bill, key){

    return bill.map(function(currentValue){
        return currentValue.bill + (currentValue.bill * (currentValue[key] / 100));
  });
};

console.dir(get_sum(data, "user_entered_tip"))
console.dir(get_bill(data, "user_entered_tip"))
```

Answer (score 1):

> A friend of mine suggested me, to learn functional programming, to work with map and reduce to create the same application.

Yup I started that that way while learning FP also :) My top tip for *conciseness* would be to

1. Separate your lists (ie `array`) from `function` (operate on 1 element only)
2. Use `map()` function bring those two together

Consider below solution -

```js
const data = [
  {"bill":120, "tipPercent": 10},
  {"bill":70, "tipPercent": 15},
  {"bill":25, "tipPercent": 20}
]

const tips = data.map(d => d.bill * d.tipPercent / 100)
const totals = data.map((d, idx) => d.bill + tips[idx])

console.log('TIPS:', tips, ', TOTALS:', totals)
```

Hope this helps your learning. 
Cheers,